# tikz - Relative alignment issue

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I have the following MNWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]

\node (start) [process] {1};
\node (node2r) [process, below right=of start] {2r};
\node (node3r) [process, below=of node2r] {3r};
\node (node4r) [process, below=of node3r] {4r};
\node (node2l) [process, below left=of start] {2l};
\node (node4l) [process, below=of node2l, left=of node4r] {4l};
\node (end) [process, below left=of node4r] {4};

\draw [arrow] (start) -| (node2r);
\draw [arrow] (start) -| (node2l);
\draw [arrow] (node2l) -- (node4l);
\draw [arrow] (node2r) -- (node3r);
\draw [arrow] (node3r) -- (node4r);
\draw [arrow] (node4r) |- (end);
\draw [arrow] (node4l) |- (end);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This generates the following output.

[image: Unintended alignment of 4l]

How do I adjust the code so that `4l` aligns with both `2l` (horizontally) and `4r` (vertically)?

---

*Bonus question:* How do I ensure that `1` and `5` aligns vertically? (Occurs if the rectangles differ in width)

Comment: `1` and `5` cannot align horizontally since it's one on top of the other, unless you mean vertically?

Comment: Damnit, corrected.

Comment: @Alenanno I understand horizontal alignment as aligning things along the horizontal axis (e.g. have same x-position, different y), so you can align `1` and `5` horizontally.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Well, I consider horizontally aligned to mean "next to each other, but on the same y", while vertical aligned to mean "on top of each other, but same x". See also [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fPZad.png).

Comment: @Alenanno Not in my vocabulary, and the tag wikis agree with me. But this is off topic here, continue in chat if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the syntax `at (coordinate|-coordinate)` for example. By the way, I switched to `\tikzset` because `\tikzstyle` is deprecated (even though it may be still supported).

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc, shapes.geometric, arrows}

\tikzset{
    process/.style={rectangle, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30},
    arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]

\node (start) [process] {1};
\node (node2r) [process, below right=of start] {2r};
\node (node3r) [process, below=of node2r] {3r};
\node (node4r) [process, below=of node3r] {4r};
\node (node2l) [process, below left=of start] {2l};
\node (node4l) [process, ] at (node2l|-node4r) {4l};
\node (end) [process] at ($(node4l)!.5!(node4r)+(0,-2cm)$) {5moretext};

\draw [arrow] (start) -| (node2r);
\draw [arrow] (start) -| (node2l);
\draw [arrow] (node2l) -- (node4l);
\draw [arrow] (node2r) -- (node3r);
\draw [arrow] (node3r) -- (node4r);
\draw [arrow] (node4r) |- (end);
\draw [arrow] (node4l) |- (end);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very neat. Any input for the bonus question?

Comment: @T'n'E See edit.

Comment: "is not deprecated", isn't it exactly **deprecated**?

Comment: @daleif Ops. :D